# What does coprime mean in the beal conjecture?

Tags: prime-factorization

$2^8+2^8=8^3$

How does coprime condition invalidate this solution?

Comment: $\gcd(2,8)=2 \neq 1$

Comment: Two positive integers are coprime if they do not share any prime factor.

Comment: Which prine factor do these share?

Comment: Dale, what are the prime factors of $8$?

Comment: 2?               Need more letters

Comment: Perhaps I miss something, but as far as I know $2^8+2^8 = 2^9 = (2^3)^3 = 8^3$ so the equation holds, how can you invalidate it?

Comment: @Yanko The equation obviously is correct. Certainly, Beal's conjecture doesn't invalidate it. However, the coprime requirement of the conjecture means this equation is not even one that it's considering.

Answer (score 2):

2, 2, and 8 are not coprime since they share a common factor of 2. Beal’s conjecture only applies if A, B, and C (the bases) share no common factor greater than 1 i.e. are coprime

Comment: Your statement that **all of the integers** in the equation have to be above $2$ is simply not true! That condition is only imposed on the exponents and not the bases. As such, the counterexample in question does not fail because there are bases of value $2$. It fails because the Greatest Common Divisor (gcd) of all three of $2$, $2$ and $8$ is not $1$. If it were $1$, then it would be a valid counterexample. Two of the bases can be $2$. However, not even one of them can be $1$.That is not allowed.

Comment: Let me clarify even further: One of the bases can be $2$. **At most two** of the bases can be $2$ (in which case the third base has to be a prime number or an odd number). However, three of the bases cannot be $2$ because then they wouldn't be co-prime.

Comment: Thank you for your correction . I updated my answer to reflect what you pointed out.